# Problema generando código QR (Primefaces)

Tags: java, html, primefaces, qrcode

He estado iniciando a programar con primefaces en NetBeans, últimamente he probado algunos componentes y encontré uno bastante útil, un generador de código QR. Pero al copiar el código de la página y descargar varias librerias me genera todos los codigos de barras, excepto la de qr. ¿me hace falta alguna librería? Muchas gracias.

Enlace del código : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/barcode.xhtml

código:

```
<h:outputText value="Codabar" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="codabar"/>

<h:outputText value="Code39" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code39" />

<h:outputText value="Code128" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="code128"/>

<h:outputText value="EAN-8" />
<p:barcode value="20123451" type="ean8"/>

<h:outputText value="EAN-13" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789012" type="ean13"/>

<h:outputText value="UPC-A (PNG)" />
<p:barcode value="01234567895" type="upca" format="png"/>

<h:outputText value="UPC-E (Vertical)" />
<p:barcode value="01234133" type="upce" orientation="90"/>

<h:outputText value="PDF417" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="pdf417"/>

<h:outputText value="DataMatrix" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="datamatrix"/>

<h:outputText value="Postnet" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="postnet"/>

<h:outputText value="QR" />
<p:barcode value="0123456789" type="qr"/>
```

[image: librerias]
[image: resultado]

Comment: Me refiero en la documentación, aqui está el link https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/barcode.xhtml

Comment: Ya lo agregué, gracias

Comment: ¿Has mirado si en el log del servidor te sale algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Gracias por responder, la verdad hasta ahora estoy comenzando con esto de java web proyects y no entiendo muy bien donde salen los errores, comunmente salen en la consola cuando son solo java, pero ahora no aparecen ... simplemente se ejecuta el xhtml pero si hay algún error no lo nombra.

Comment: Primefaces (y tecnologías web) se ejecutan en un servidor de aplicaciones (Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss...); lo único que hace Netbeans es lanzar el servidor de aplicaciones. Mira donde tienes el servidor y podrás encontrar los archivos de log.

Comment: Ah si, al comienzo me pide un servidor y por defecto selecciono "Glassfish", ¿me podrías decir cómo lo ejecuto? en qué parte lo puedo ubicar para mirar los errores? Muchas gracias

Comment: La verdad, no uso mucho Netbeans. Si curioseas por la configuración del proyecto o del programa seguramente encontrarás donde está instalado el servidor; o directamente busca "glassfish" en el explorador de archivos. Una vez que lo tengas, el fichero de log debería ser fácil de encontrar.

Comment: Entendido, muchas gracias